# Finding a path which visits certain nodes of choice in a graph

Tags: graph, path, include, vertices

Lets suppose we have a undirected graph and I pick some arbitrary starting vertex. Now from that vertex I want to find a path that travels through some given vertices of choice. For example, lets say I have vertices(A,B,C,D,E,F,G) all connected in some undirected way and I pick vertex A as my starting vertex. Now I want to find a path that goes through C,D and E and as soon as I have found a path(it cant be any path just has to include those vertices) I want to stop the search and return it. What is a good approach of going about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> it cant be any path just has to include those vertices

Using the Dijkstra algotithm

1. Find path from A to C
2. Find path from C to D
3. Find path from D to E
4. stop

Comment: By any chance is it possible to do this using depth first search in one traversal?